# Reaction between hydrobromic acid and sodium borate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

> Write the reaction for a a sodium borate solution being titrated by hydrobromic acid, assuming sodium borate is represented by $\ce{Na3BO3(aq)}$.

I think this is a simple double replacement reaction:

$$\ce{Na3BO3(aq) + 3 HBr(aq) -> 3 NaBr(aq) + H3BO3(aq)}\tag{R1}$$

Official solution without explanation:

$$\ce{Na3BO3(aq) + HBr(aq) -> 2 NaBr(aq) + NaH2BO3(aq) }\tag{R2}$$

I don't understand how the official reaction was reached. Why should a sodium cation take the place of a hydrogen?

Comment: It is rather $\ce{Na[B(OH)4]}$

Comment: The whole task seems to me like being made up. Who would use HBr for titration and end titration with alkalic solution ? I also do not believe much in Na3BO3(aq).

Comment: Don't forget, in contrast to e.g., $\ce{S}$ in $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{B}$ in $\ce{H3BO3}$ (or $\ce{B(OH)3}$) still has *the* electron gap characteristic for *Lewis* acids like $\ce{AlCl3}$.

Comment: Poutnik is right. $\ce{Na3BO3}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Maurice Googling "trisodium orthoborate, na3bo3" give me 168 hits. The promising results are [this](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5993&context=masters_theses) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292820855_Autocausticizing_of_smelt_with_sodium_borates).

Comment: The 2nd link states: "Both NaBO2 and Na2B4O7 were found to react readily with molten Na2CO3 at any Na:B molar larger than 3:1 to form trisodium borate (Na3BO3). The formation of Na3BO3 as a reaction product means that the amount of borate required for the autocausticizing reactions can be substantially lowered than previously suggested."

Comment: @NilayGhosh. I was thinking of aqueous chemistry. In the same reference, it is said that $\ce{Na3BO3}$ does exist. But it is immediately decomposed by water into $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{NaBO2}$

Comment: Notice I have written Na3BO3(aq) not just Na3BO3.

Answer (score 2):

The borate anions are a series whose charge depends upon pH. A good (and long, but probably still incomplete) reference is https://europepmc.org/article/pmc/6470676.

[image]

The request for an equation identifies two starting materials but does not suggest an endpoint, and there are many. The OP gives a *complete* reaction: react all the possible basic anions with acidic HBr. Good answer. The official solution is a partial neutralization - to what pH? The suggestion of titration needs to say what indicator or what pH is the endpoint, or else it must have been explained in class beforehand.

Or, the question is just a bad one - or a trap.

Comment: Wikipedia says at boric acid that *Polyborate anions are formed at pH 7–10 if the boron concentration is higher than about 0.025 mol/L. The best known of these is the 'tetraborate' ion, found in the mineral borax.*

Comment: @James Gaidis. Where have you found these diagrams of Boron stuff versus pH ?

Comment: @Maurice: the reference for the diagram is in the third line of my answer.